# Monadic transformation on a list, done in three ways

Tags: haskell, comparative-review, monads

I am working my way through the [Haskell Book](http://haskellbook.com/) and ran into the exercises at the end of the Monad chapter(18). One in particular asked to define a function with the following signature:

```
meh :: Monad m => [a] -> (a -> m b) -> m [b]
```

So I did. I found this routine difficult to implement at first, but once I understood what I was doing and what I needed to do a little better I figured it out.

I have three versions of the routine, my first attempt, a slightly refactored attempt, and a final attempt using do-notation. I was wondering if anyone can give advice on how I could potentially refactor this routine further, or how I can make my implementation better. I feel like I can make the routine far cleaner than I have it, but I am not sure how.

**WARNING: If you are reading the Haskell Book and want to work through the exercises yourself, I recommend you do not read any further**

Here are all three implementations

```
-- Attempt #1 with helper routine
meh :: Monad m => [a] -> (a -> m b) -> m [b]
meh list fn = doWork list (return $ []) fn
  where 
    doWork (x:xs) base f
      | length xs == 0 = (addToMonad x base f) >>= (\x -> return $ reverse x)
      | otherwise = doWork xs (addToMonad x base f) f

addToMonad x baseMonad fn = do
  someVal <- (fn x)
  base <- baseMonad
  return $ someVal:base

-- Attempt #2 with a fold
meh' :: Monad m => [a] -> (a -> m b) -> m [b]
meh' list fn = (foldl (\acc x -> (fn x) >>= (\y -> acc >>= (\z -> return $ y:z))) (return $ []) list) >>= (\x -> return $ reverse x)

-- Attempt #3 with a fold and do-notation
mehDo :: Monad m => [a] -> (a -> m b) -> m [b]
mehDo list fn = do 
  final <- (foldl (\acc x -> do
    val <- (fn x) 
    mList <- acc
    return $ val:mList)
    (return $ []) list)
  return $ reverse final
```

I want to *say* my last implementation is the easiest to read (it would be easier with better names, IMO) but I don't really *know* that it is. I am not super experienced in the ways of Haskell, so to be frank I read the routines really slowly regardless.

Anyway, advice or tips on how to make this cleaner would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that the idiomatic way to write this function in Haskell is by composing a more primitive one with a map. Indeed, given the type signature of `meh`, it is very tempting to "prepare" a list of all the `m b` actions and then combine them in order:

```
meh :: Monad m => [a] -> (a -> m b) -> m [b]
meh xs f = combine (f <$> xs)
```

Now, `combine` has type `[m b] -> m [b]`. To process that list, we can use a fold. You have used `foldl` in your examples but you ended up reversing the list which is a clear sign that you may have wanted a `foldr` instead. And we can indeed do that:

```
combine :: Monad m => [m b] -> m [b]
combine = foldr (\ x xs -> (:) <$> x <*> xs) (return [])
```

Here the functor `(<$>)` and applicative `(<*>)` combinators allow to write something that looks a bit direct style (we are basically using `(:)` to construct a list by giving its head and tail) but that takes care of the monadic actions.

Answer (score 1):

As I don't have a copy of the Haskell Book, I don't know what is already known at that point. But `meh` is a standard function, namely `flip mapM` or `forM`:

```
import Control.Monad (forM)

meh :: Monad m => [a] -> (a -> m b) -> m [b]
meh = forM
```

But that's cheating, right? So we can try another approach instead, namely split the functionality into two functions:

```
meh :: Monad m => [a] -> (a -> m b) -> m [b]
meh xs f = sequence' (map f xs)
```

`sequence` is again a standard function, so we're still somewhat cheating. However, we can write it our own:

```
sequence' :: Applicative f => [f a] -> f [a]
sequence' []     = pure []
sequence' (x:xs) = (:) <$> x <*> sequence' xs
```

Note that `Applicative` is enough to define both `meh` and `sequence'`. The original `sequence` is usually defined as follow, by the way:

```
sequence []     = return []
sequence (x:xs) = do
    y  <- x
    ys <- sequence xs
    return (y : ys)
```

Which isn't too far off of your last variant. But if you're already using `do` notation, I would pair it with pattern-matching:

```
mehDo :: Monad m => [a] -> (a -> m b) -> m [b]
mehDo []     f = return []
mehDo (x:xs) f = do
   y  <- f x
   ys <- mehDo xs f
   return (y : ys)
```

Which, in my point of view, is the easiest variant to read. But if you use `meh` in your own code, you're going to use `forM` either way.

Comment: This was very informative. It is neat to see things like Foldable and Traversable that can be exchanged with lists as you get deeper into Haskell. Thanks for your time.